# How do I get sphinx or reStructuredText to fit and resize the width of the content to the width of the window?

Tags: css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a working html build on sphinx v1.1.3 and html pages automatically resize as I change the window size.

If I upgraded to sphinx 1.7.4 the page displays with fixed width, with black background on the right. Changing the window size doesn't increase the width beyond a certain max, but shrinking it still shrinks the size of the content and the text wraps. This new behavior is different than v1.1.3 and nothing other than the version of Sphinx was changed.

I have nothing fancy - looking at html source the only .css files included are classic.css, pygments.css, and html_style.css. Can anyone suggest where to look next to solve the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding "body_max_width": "none" to html_theme_options in conf.py

Comment: what value for `html_theme` were you using?